# Problem with search numbers in filenames

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search

After migration of document libraries from SP2010 to SP2013 version users faced with search problems.

Most part of files has names like `СТО-03.120.00-ЧТН-073-10` (It's russian) and users get used to search documents by typing last digits, for example `073-10`.

I know that SharePoint 2013 doesn't support wildcards by default and you have to search the whole word. Also I know that dash `-` SharePoint 2013 consider as word breaker.

So, we have a file in an document library with name `СТО-03.120.00-ЧТН-073-10.doc`

In crowler log that file is successfully crawled.

If we're searching:

```
СТО-03.120.00-ЧТН - File is found

СТО-03.120.00 -  File is found
```

`ЧТН-073-10` - Folder with the same name is found. Inside the folder is our file. Not bad.

`073-10` - File not found

In Sharepoint 2010 it's working just fine. What can we do to make the same search in 2013?

I think the problem is that sharepoint does not consider numbers as words, any ideas what we can do to make it work?